# Writing variable length records to a file using FileHelper?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using `FileHelper` to write records to a flat file.
First 20 fields of these records are fixed, if the values are empty, spaces will be filled.
Whereas the last 4 fields are optional, if they all are empty, those positions should not be filled with spaces. But `FileHelper` keep filling those positions with spaces.

Is it possible to achieve this using `FileHelper`?

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowVariableLength)] 
public class MyReport
{
    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    public string field1;

    [FieldFixedLength(10)] 
    public string field2;
    ...
    [FieldFixedLength(96)] 
    [FieldOptional]
    public string field32;

    [FieldFixedLength(96)]
    [FieldOptional]
    public string field33;

    [FieldFixedLength(96)]
    [FieldOptional]
    public string field34;

    [FieldFixedLength(96)]
    [FieldOptional]
    public string field35;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to add conditional statements using FileHelpers..?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any extra separators in an [`AfterWriteRecord` event](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.AfterWriteRecordHandler.html).

Here's a working example:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public partial class Person
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Optional1;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Optional2;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Optional3;
}      

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Person>();
        engine.AfterWriteRecord += engine_AfterWriteRecord;
        var export = engine.WriteString(
                     new Person[] { 
                       new Person() { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Bloggs" } 
                     });
        Assert.AreEqual("Joe,Bloggs" + Environment.NewLine, export);
    }

    static void engine_AfterWriteRecord(EngineBase engine, AfterWriteEventArgs<Person> e)
    {
        // trim trailing empty separators
        e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.TrimEnd(',');
    }
}
```

Comment: For people who look at this and think that normal naming conventions suggest that this should be BeforeWrite not AfterWrite, the code actually calls BeforeWrite then converts the fields to a single line of text, calls AfterWrite and then actually writes the text.  There is no true ***"after the data is written to the file"*** event and AfterWrite is really a Pre-write event still.

Answer (score 0):

This would be, I suspect, because you have the FixedLength() attribute on each of the optional fields.  The optional attribute, as far as I am aware, only really appears to importing so that if there is no value (null) nothing is set.

Confirmation of that can be found here: http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FieldOptionalAttribute.htm

Considering what you are attempting to do, I think you will need to write a custom converter that would handle this for you and take off the fixedwidth attribute.

```
public sealed class FixedWidth96Converter : ConverterBase
{
    public override string FieldToString(object from)
    {
        string val = from as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            return val.PadLeft(96, ' ');
        }
        return base.FieldToString(from);
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        return from;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would concur with the FieldOptional statement because when writing out, your column headers must match the data and since FileHelpers would not know that all columns are blank untli it processed all fields, there is no generic way for it to do it.  You can remove fields using the .RemoveField() function but you would be removing that field from ALL rows not just one.